# Docker Compose - Connect two containers with separate compose files and forward one port from host to one container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I started with one compose file that contained all my services I want to run. To be able to rebuild and start them independent from each other I want to have each in its own compose file.

As a test setup I use two nginx servers. One to server the page and one that acts as proxy to the nginx server with the page.

If I just split the compose files, the other nginx server is no longer reachable. To connect them again I created an own network "services" and attached all containers to it. As a result the proxy nginx can find the nginx with the page again (in other cases I get an error because the other nginx is not reachable).
Sadly the port forwarding seems to be disabled at my configuration. If I comment out the network definition the port mapping works fine.

What I try to find is a solution to connect both nginx containers and be also able to setup a portforwarding from the host to one container.

As I created the network with portainer (also tried directly with docker cli) I defined the network as external.

The compose file of the nginx with the page is

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx2:
    container_name: 'nginx2'
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - services
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "8092:80"
    volumes:
      - ./conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./conf/index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
      - ./data/log:/var/log/nginx

networks:
  services:
    external: true
```

The compose file of nginx that acts as proxy is

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx1:
    container_name: 'nginx1'
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "8091:80"
    networks:
      - services
    volumes:
      - ./conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./conf/index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
      - ./data/log:/var/log/nginx

networks:
  services:
    external: true
```

The nginx proxy setting is

```
proxy_pass      http://nginx2;
```

The network definition is

```
name: services
scope: local
Driver: ridge
Attachable: true
Internal: true
IPAM Driver: default
IPAM Subnet: 192.168.33.0/20
IPAM Gateway: 192.168.32.1
```

It would really be great if someone could point me out what I'm missing to connect both containers and have portforwarding for one container at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
The compose files are correct.

The problem was a wrong network definition.
My nertwork "services" was defined with the parameter "Internal" set to "true".
This disables the port forwarding.

With the network parameter "Internal" set to "false" everything works as expected.

Here the full configuration of the network

```
name: services
scope: local
Driver: ridge
Attachable: true
Internal: false
IPAM Driver: default
IPAM Subnet: 192.168.33.0/20
IPAM Gateway: 192.168.32.1
```